# How do I get the frequency of my dictionary value as it changes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a novice, just started learning how to program.

I will to ask how do I get the frequency/count of a value changed within a key?

for instance:

```
user_input= input("Enter a word")


dict = {"Coffee": ["I love coffee."], "Tea": ["I love tea."]}
```

so if the user selects coffee, he/she can amend by adding or delete that value.
He/she is then able to view the number of time the key "coffee" is being amended.

---

I appreciate the prompt responses from everyone! But maybe this example below will be a little more comprehensive.

---

if user selects coffee, they can either have the option to delete or append new sentence to the existing key.

So for every value that is being deleted or added: it will be recorded

For example: If I will to change the Coffee's value, that will 1, thereafter, if I will to delete the Coffee's value again, it will be the 2nd time I have amend the value within coffee.

output: Revision changed on "Coffee" : 2

Comment: this can return number of items in key _coffee_ `len(dict["Coffee"])`

Comment: hi there! Thank you for your response! But how do I get the number of time, the sentence within the coffee is being changed?

Comment: in your update function - where the input value is updated to dict, use counter var

Comment: You can't do it just like this. You need to keep counters for each dict member that will increase by 1 when someone amends that member of the dictionary.

Comment: Sidenote: If you want to keep the inclusive language, use "they" instead of "he/she". It's better to read and widely accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but if I am, then an if statement should do the trick, every time the user picks coffee it'll add one to it's corresponding counter and same thing with tea, then you do whatever you want with those values:

```
user_input= input("Enter a word")


dict = {"Coffee": ["I love coffee."], "Tea": ["I love tea."]}

if user_input == "Coffee":
    coffee_amend += 1
if user_input == "Tea":
    tea_amend += 1
```

This is my first time ever responding to anything so please tell me if I did anything wrong; I hope you found this helpful!

Comment: hi there! Thanks for your response! I will try to work one this!

Answer (score 0):

First modify the structure of the dictionary that you are using like below:

```
dic = {"Coffee": [["I love coffee."],0], "Tea": [["I love tea."],0]}
```

As you can see I have maintained, the count of number of times changed and It value at the key.

Now make two functions for changing the value at a particular key and getting the count of number of times value changed at that particular key

```
def changeKeyValue(dic, key, value):
  dic[key][1] += 1 
  dic[key][0] = value

changeKeyValue(dic,'Coffee',None)

def getNumTimes(dic,key):
  return dic[key][1]
```

Now use these functions to get the result you want :

```
print("Key value changed", getNumTimes(dic,"Coffee"))
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want something that interacts with the user. This is not super elegant but it is easy to understand:

```
dict = {"Coffee": ["I love coffee."], "Tea": ["I love tea."]}
cnt_dict = {}
cont = True
while cont == True:
    user_input = input("Enter a word")
    user_input2 = input('What would you like to do?')
    if user_input2 == 'delete':
        dict[user_input] = '' #sets the value to empty list
    if user_input2 == 'ammend':
        user_input3 = input('What would you like to change to?')
        dict[user_input] = user_input3
    if user_input in cnt_dict.keys():
        cnt_dict[user_input] += 1
    else:
        cnt_dict[user_input] = 1
    print(cnt_dict)
    input_4 = input('continue? (y/n)')
    if input_4 != 'y':
       cont = False
```

cnt_dict is a dictionary which counts the number of times each key is changed. Hopefully this helps. Edit: Obviously there will be problems if you are trying to add things not currently in dict but you can build off this.